# AC motor 3 wiring how to connect to EU plug

Tags: motor, ac

Hello electronics stackexchange,

a friend gifted me an electric motor he didnt need any more. It looks exactly like this ans also has (nearly) the same numbers on it :  https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/390210-001-390209-001-12V-server-fans/1913237_32589390473.html

I have use for this one, but am not sure how to connect it to my power supply (Germany, EU Plug). Is this an more or less easy task or am I better off just not touching it?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a three-phase motor but the Aliexpress listing says both 12V and 230V which is unhelpful.

It might be that if you dismantled the fan-duct housing you would find the motor inside has more helpful markings.

When friends offload their dusty old junk on to you, there is often a good reason they never found a use for it.

You need some other parts

[image]

Rough translation:

Ducted Fan thingamajig
30A electrical whatsit
Controller/Tester gadget
positive and negative leads
electrical supply

Like this $15 [3-phase 360W DC 12V Brushless High-Power Motor Speed Control PWM Controller 30A](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-phase-360W-DC-12V-Brushless-High-Power-Motor-Speed-Control-PWM-Controller-30A-/111824499004)

Comment: Thank you. I always thought the "12v" was part of the model number or something like that. The wires are quite heavy, about 2 to 3 mm diameter each. BTW, he didnt really offload junk to me, he said it was never used and that he wants to throw it away.

Comment: Again thank you RedGrittyBrick. I received the controller today and I am not sure about the wiring. My controller looks exactly like the one in the image. I connect the red wire directly to the battery + and the black one directly to the -. But how do i connect the three outgoing (black coloured) wires to the fan? The controller lights up an LED if i connect it to the battery but the fan does not move, no matter how i wire it. any clues on that?